# iOS app with a strange structure

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the code of an application but inside it there aren't ".m" files, but app works fine and runs on device; is it possible? I don't understand this fact, can you explain me this case?

Comment: Could you give more details? What IS inside the application folder?

Comment: What files are listed in the Compile Sources build phase of the project’s target? When you build the application, what does the build log show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app is calling into a file with one .a suffix, that means it's an already compiled library and the original source code is on the original author's machine.

You can ask him/her nicely for the source code to that .a library but unless it's open source, chances are high they're not going to provide it.

Using the "nm" tool to get the exported symbols is one trick, but whatever API's you're supposed to use in the library are probably visible and documented in the .h file.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the @interface and @implementation code in 1 .h-file no problem. It will still work and if you do it doesn't need a .m-file.

The seperation between .h and .m is just default by xcode but not mandatory to stick to as you can see.

Comment: ok but in .h there is not instruction of method, I must say that inside the main bundle there is a file exec, but there is not instructions; for example with a button you can close a view but there isn't the code

Comment: They might have been Utility classes then.
A utility class is a class that defines a set of methods that perform common, often re-used functions. Most utility classes define these common methods under static scope.

Comment: this file is a file exec and is name is customlib.a , how can I open it?

Comment: You can't open it, search the source code of this library.
You can type 
`nm customlib.a` 
in console to find out some info, but it will not help you to discover code of the library.

Comment: where I find source code of this library?